# app.yaml configuration in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

My project is simple, it contains a folder its name templates where index.html is located, and another folder called static contains another folder called js where a simple JavaScript file is located its name is myScript.js.

The problem that I am facing is the configuration of app.yaml (I think that I am not doing it correct), because if I include the JavaScript code in index.html everything works fine, but when I am placing the JavaScript file outside index.html then the application doesn't run correct.

Here is my app.yaml configuration

```
application: mzngl
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: .*
  script: main.app


- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /index\.html
  script: main.app

- url: /
 script: main.app


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest 

 - name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

And here is index.html contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>External JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> myFunction is stored in an external file called "myScript.js".</p>

<script src="../static/js/myScript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me find a solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: use : <script src="/js/myScript.js"></script>

Comment: @voscausa, Thank you, I had tried your suggestion but the issue wasn't solved, my main folder in mzngl contains two folders (static, and templates), then static contains js which contains myScript.js

Comment: And this url: .* matches everything. Move in the to the end of your app.yaml.

Comment: @voscausa, I don't know if I am following your suggestions correct but the issue still without solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler section:

```
handlers:

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /index\.html
  script: main.app

- url: /(.*)
  script: main.app
```

Now you can use in your index.html

```
<script src="/js/myScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't know why it is not working, hopefully I am not doing some stupid thing in some place.

Comment: do you have a working example that runs external JavaScript, so I can understand how it works ?

Comment: you can always test with: http://localhost:8080/js/myScript.js or using your http://mzngl,.appspot.com/js/myScript.js

Comment: Thank you voscausa, now it is working, I stoped the Google App Engine launcher, then restarted again and run the application, and your suggestion worked.